# how to get record for which given date falls between two dates of same column in PostgreSql

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

My table is having data e.g. empcode designation code and promotion date, I want to get what was an employee's designation on some given date. for eg.

```
EmpCode DesignationCode PromotionDate
101         50           2010-01-25 
101         10           2014-01-01
101         11           2015-01-01
102         10           2009-10-01              
103         15           2015-01-01
```

now if I check designation as on 2014-02-01 it should give result as following

```
EmpCode DesignationCode PromotionDate
101         10           2014-01-01
102         10           2009-10-01
```

Can anyone please tell what query should I write ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not the lowest date, Highest date which is less then or equal to the given date.
2010-01-25 is not include in expected output because employee 101 got one more promotion after this date (on 2014-01-01) which is the having the actual designation code as on 2014-02-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (EmpCode) EmpCode, DesignationCode, PromotionDate
FROM mytable
WHERE PromotionDate <= '2014-02-01'
ORDER BY EmpCode, PromotionDate DESC
```

The query first filters out any records having a `PromotionDate` that is past given date, i.e. `'2014-02-01'`.

Using [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) `(EmpCode)` we get one row per `EmpCode`. This is the one having the most recent `PromotionDate` (this is achieved by placing `PromotionDate DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/65b59/2)